# failed to push some refs to heroku

Tags: python, sqlite, heroku, flask

I've looked through multiple logs of similar issues and tried a few fixes. None of the fixes I've found have fixed the issue so I'm hoping uploading my own will help!

My file structure is:

```
.git(folder)
__psycache__(folder)
static(folder)
templates(folder)
mysite.py(file)
Procfile(file)
requirements.txt(file)
```

When I attempt to push via :

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

It doesn't go through and sends me an error message (message below):

I'm trying to push a python flask application to heroku but everytime I push it, I get the same errors:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.7
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting altgraph==0.16.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9198a2bd578560abc42ffe1b42e04366/requirements.txt (line 1))

remote:
remote:            Error running configure
remote:            ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "build.py", line 1321, in cmd_build_wx
remote:                wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-3mun_e25/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 375, in main
remote:                "Error running configure")
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-3mun_e25/wxPython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
remote:                raise builder.BuildError(msg)
remote:            buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error running configure
remote:            Finished command: build_wx (0m6.238s)
remote:            Finished command: build (0m6.238s)
remote:            Command '"/app/.heroku/python/bin/python" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3mun_e25/wxPython/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7rgfyfwr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3mun_e25/wxPython/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to jasomegathon.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/jasomegathon.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/jasomegathon.git'
```

I took out a few lines in the middle due to character limit.

Other notes:
- I am in the master branch
- my Procfile reads "web: gunicorn app:app"
- I'm using SQLite but I am planning to switch to postgress
- This is my first web app pushing to Heroku
- I'm on a windows machine, but using a linux based git bash line

My requirements folder:

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4
Jinja2==2.10
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
macholib==1.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
openpyxl==2.5.12
pefile==2018.8.8
Pillow==5.4.1
pycodestyle==2.4.0
PyInstaller==3.4
pylint==2.2.2
pytz==2018.9
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.7.1
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
SQLAlchemy==1.2.16
urllib3==1.24.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.10.11
WTForms==2.2.1
wxPython==4.0.4
```

Comment: Is mysite.py your main file that you're using to start your flask app? Also, does your flask app work locally and what does your requirements.txt file look like?

Comment: @NathanWright It is the name of my main file, and it does work locally with all functionality in tact. I updated my post to include the requirements folder contents. Thanks for taking a look at my issue!

Comment: Thank you, I have suggested 2 steps. I am assuming you have already  ran heroku create? Also, I am assuming your requirements.txt file is correct. If those steps don't resolve your issue we will take a look at the above mentioned next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the following:

1. It looks like you're missing a `runtime.txt` file, this file specifies the Python runtime environment you wish to target on Heroku. Add the following file to your project base directory (I am assuming you're using Python version 3.7.0 if not just change it to the appropriate version:)

   **runtime.txt:**

   `python-3.7.0`
2. Your `Procfile` looks off please change it to the following, since **mysite.py** is your point of entry for your application:

**Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn mysite:app
```

3. Can you remove this from your `requirements.txt` file: `wxPython==4.0.4?` Heroku allows you to host web applications on the cloud and doesn't support native GUI interfaces as far as I know.
4. try this as your requirements.txt file as it has picked up some unwanted libs from the `pip freeze` cmd

**requirements.txt:**

```
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
decorator==4.1.2
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
future==0.16.0
geocoder==1.32.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
ratelim==0.1.6
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.14
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.1
```

Comment: I attempted the changes you mentioned and still have the same error. To your previous comment, I have run heroku create and git freeze to get the requirements.

Comment: You're creating a web app right? Not a GUI interface with wxPython right? I suspect your pip freeze has picked up all your previous system wide library installs.

Comment: Yes. It's just html, css, and python(Flask).

Comment: Ok your requirements.txt file needs to change it has everything in it your have ever downloaded.

Comment: You are a beautiful human being! I've been trying to figure this out for the past two days haha. That worked and it's now uploaded. Thank you so much! Now to migrate to postgress!

Comment: Np, glad it helped. Just a word of advice I would consider using python virtual environments to create a safe sandbox for developement. Then you can experiment and blow it away if something gets out of sorts and just start over. Additionally, you don't have to worry about messing with your system level python configs. Take a look at this tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ Virtual environments will save you future headaches. Happy Coding

Comment: I did, but I'm less than 15 rep so it doesn't show it publicly